# Sounddevice - Test callback fucntion

Tags: python, callback, pytest, python-sounddevice

I have some code that uses the sounddevice library in a callback function. I need to use pytest inorder to test this callback function.
I am simply trying to test if the callback function does not raise an exception.
however, pytest keeps reporting that the "indata" parameter of the callback function is not defined. Although, I am importing my callback function into my test file. FYI, my original code is working fine, no issues with callback indata.
I am rather new to python coding, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

from project import callback

def test_callback():

```
try:
    callback(indata, frames, time, status)

except ValueError:
    assert False
```

FROM PYTEST...

_________ test_callback _________

```
def test_callback():

    try:
```

> ```
>       callback(indata, frames, time, status)
> ```

**E           NameError: name 'indata' is not defined**